# How can i optimize this jquery code

Tags: jquery, optimization

Is there a shorter more optimized way to write the following code.

```
$("button.idiv").click(function(){
        var elm = $('<div id=divid' + divId + ' class=aaa></div>');
        elm.resizable().draggable({ containment: "p", stack:"div" }).appendTo('p');
        divId++;
});

$("button.ispan").click(function(){
        var elm = $('<img id=spanid' + spanId + ' class=aaas src="Dollar.png"/>');
        elm.resizable().parent().draggable({ containment: "p", stack:"div" }).appendTo('p');
        spanId++;
});

$("button.itext").click(function(){
        var elm = $('<div id=textid' + textId + ' class=aaat>some text</div>');
        elm.resizable().draggable({ containment: "p", stack:"div" }).appendTo('p');
        textId++;
});
```

Comment: Is it running slowly? Do you have output from a profiler that shows where the bottleneck is?

Comment: No it's not running slow, But i find my self repeating and i want to know if i can write this code in a shorter more optimized way. I still have 10 more button clicks functions to call in addition to the 3 i already have in the code above.

Comment: @alex So you're not looking for an "optimization". You're looking for a way to keep code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Lots of people (me included) dislike premature optimizations :p

Comment: @alex Are the funny auto-generated ids required?

Comment: @alex - it would help if we can see the structure of the markup.

Comment: Yes, id, class and element type will be different for every function. All id's start at 1 and increment every time the button is clicked. All of the functions have draggable and resizable, except the img tag has parent() added. I don't know if such code can be written in a shorter way where it can be reused to add more button functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to do something like this? The code might look like more, but I've tried to remove as much of the repeating as possible and also added lots of newlines and tabs to make it easier to read. Any difference in performance should be neglible.

```
$("button.idiv, button.itext, button.ispan").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this),
       draggableOptions = {
               containment: "p", 
               stack:"div"
       };
   if ($this.is(".idiv, .itext")) {
       var elm = $("<div>"),
           cls = "aaa";
       if ($this.is(".idiv")) {
           id = "divid"+divId;
           divId++;
       } else {
           id = "textid"+textId;
           cls += "t";
           textId++;
       }
       elm
           .addClass(cls)
           .attr("id", id)
           .resizable();
   } else {
       var elm = $("<img>")
           .attr("id", "spanid"+spanId)
           .attr("src", "Dollar.png")
           .addClass(cls+"s")
           .resizable();
       elm = elm.parent();
       spanId++;
   }
   elm.draggable(draggableOptions)
      .appendTo("p");
});
```

Comment: Very clean. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Since all three sets of code do *almost* the same thing *except* for some individual values, this is the perfect opportunity to consolidate the differences with some sort of configuration object:

```
var types = {
    div: {
        id: 1,
        element: "<div>",
        className: "aaa"
    },
    span: {
        id: 1,
        element: "<img src='Dollar.png'>",
        className: "aaas",
        parentDraggable: true
    },
    text: {
        id: 1,
        element: "<div>",
        className: "aaat"
    }
};
```

Then the code simply becomes:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), t;
    // See if the button has any class matching one of the defined "types"
    for (var i in types) {
        if (types.hasOwnProperty(i) && $this.hasClass("i" + i)) {
            t = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!t) return;

    // Your condensed code
    var elem = $(types[t].element)
        .attr("id", t + "id").addClass(types[t].className)
        .resizable();
    if (types[t].parentDraggable) elem = elem.parent();
    elem.draggable({ containment: "p", stack:"div" }).appendTo('p');

    // Increment ID on the type itself
    types[t].id++;
});
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't mirror the behavior of his code. There's more to it then just different class names and elements. Notice the `.parent()` that's set to `draggable` for `.ispan` and `src` for the `img` element. Also, your example will select all `button` elements which is far from optimal.

Comment: @Marcus, I overlooked these, thanks for pointing them out. I'll modify the code to suit. Attaching the click to all button elements is less efficient, but more flexible when you need to add new "types". If you look at the poster's comments, he actually wants 10 of these but in the example only showed 3. Listing each class as part of the selector is quite tedious and error-prone.

Comment: cool! Well, perhaps we should have a second `class` to tell which one to select then. That's how I would do it atleast :)

Comment: @Marcus, I absolutely agree. That's something for @alex to decide then.